The derivative for $\arcsin(2x)$
So by the chain rule I have
$$\arcsin'(2x) = \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{1-(2x)^2}} \cdot 2 = \dfrac{2}{\sqrt{1-4x^2}}$$
However, my friend suggested that we can use the following method that arrives at a different answer:
\begin{equation}
    \begin{split}
        \sin(\arcsin(2x)) &= 2x \\
        \dfrac{d}{dx} \sin(\arcsin(2x)) &= \dfrac{d}{dx}2x \\
        \cos(\arcsin(2x)) \arcsin'(2x) \cdot 2 &= 2 \\
        \cos(\arcsin(2x)) \arcsin'(2x) &= 1 \\
        \arcsin'(2x) &= \dfrac{1}{\cos(\arcsin(2x))} \\
                    &= \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{1-4x^2}} \\
    \end{split}
\end{equation}
I couldn't find the logic fallacy in our methods, so please point out the problem with the solutions we have.
Edit 16:17 UTC+8 2024/4/3: I mistyped the minus symbol in the derivative as plus, now they are corrected.

In your computation $\arcsin'(2x)$ is the derivative of $\arcsin$ evaluated at $2x$, which is not the same as the derivative of $\arcsin(2x)$. What you need is $$
\frac{\mathrm{d}}{{\mathrm{d}x}}\sin (\arcsin (2x)) = \cos (\arcsin (2x))\left( {\frac{\mathrm{d}}{{\mathrm{d}x}}\arcsin (2x)} \right).
$$

Sorry Gary - I just saw your comment once I had finished tidying up my answer. You put it in a more concise form, hence, better answer.

You have the wrong formula for the derivative of the arcsine. $\frac{d}{dx}\arcsin(u) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-u^2}}(u')$.

Please consider accepting one of the answers below, if it was helpful. By the way: Very welcome to Math Stackexchange!

$$f(x):=\arcsin(x)$$
$$g(x):=2x$$
$$(f\circ g)'(x) = \frac{2}{\sqrt{1-4x^2}}$$
$$f'(2x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-4x^2}}$$
The problem lies in the fact, that the function $g(x)$ mostly is written just like an evaluation point. The right answer depends on whether you have to read $2x$ as a function, i.e. $g(x)=2x$ or you have to read $2x$ as an evaluation point.
I personally would read
$$\arcsin'(2x)=f'(2x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-4x^2}}$$

I suspect what has happened is that you have used $\arcsin'(2x)$ to mean two different things: the derivative $\frac{d}{dt}(\arcsin{(t)})$ evaluated at $t=2x$ as well as (what I expect you intended) $\frac{d}{dx}(\arcsin{2x})$.
To overcome this, I recommend a $u$-substitution:
Let $u=\arcsin{2x}$
$\sin{u}=2x$
(By implicit differentiation): $\cos{u}\times \frac{du}{dx}=2$
$\frac{du}{dx} = \frac{2}{\cos{u}}$
$\frac{d}{dx}(\arcsin{2x})=\frac{2}{\cos{(\arcsin{2x}})}$
$\frac{d}{dx}(\arcsin{2x})=\frac{2}{\sqrt{1-(2x)^{2}}}$
Which is the result you obtained earlier (as expected)

The derivative of $\arcsin(x)$ is $\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}$. There is a sign error in your post.

There is a difference between$\newcommand{\dv}[2]{\frac{\mathrm d#1}{\mathrm d#2}}$$\dv{}xf(2x)$ and $f^\prime(2x)$. Define $g(x)=2x$, then they are, respectively, $(f\circ g)^\prime(x)=f^\prime(g(x))g^\prime(x)$ and $f^\prime(g(x))$. Since $g^\prime(x)=2$ here, this leads to the difference between the two answers.
Hope this helps. :)
